# Stub return value for all inputs in Rhino Mocks

Tags: .net, rhino-mocks

I am stubbing the return value of a method using rhino mocks. However, I want to return the same dummy value for any argument that is passed in.

How do I do this without pre-registering every input to return the same output?

Comment: thanks for the answers. The were all good so I picked the top one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

_testHelper is helper class where you are returning a dummy value from GetMethodValue(). you have to write GetMethodValue() in your _testHelper class.

```
SetupResult.For(_Repository.MethodName(null)).IgnoreArguments().Return(_testHelper.GetMethodNameResultValue());
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd use `MyClass.Expect(x=>x.MyMethod(someArg)).Return(stubValue).IgnoreArguments()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `IgnoreArguments()` constraint as shown below:

```
mockedInstance.Expect(instance => instance.MethodCall(null))
              .IgnoreArguments()
              .Return(preDefinedValue)
              .Repeat()
              .Any();
```

Also by specifying `Repeat().Any()` `preDefinedValue` will be returned for each call of a method.

See [Rhino Mocks wiki](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1#WhatsNewinRhinoMocksDF) for more examples.