# How to stub the return value on a mocked method in SinonJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, sinon

I want to do something like the following:

```
sinon.mock(obj)
.expects('func')
.atLeast(1)
.withArgs(args)
.returns(somePredefinedReturnValue);
```

Where I expect everything up to and including withArgs, but then I need to stub the return value of the method so that when it returns it doesn't break the rest of the execution flow within the method under test.

The reason I'm doing this is because I found out that some of my REST endpoint tests will silently pass when they should really be failing if a stubbed method with a callback that has an assertion inside of it doesn't get called.  I'm trying to verify that these callbacks are actually getting called so that my tests don't give false positives.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stub return value for all inputs in Rhino Mocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498995/stub-return-value-for-all-inputs-in-rhino-mocks)

Comment: @PaulSweatte I'm using Sinon, not Rhino.  The Rhino solution might not work for Sinon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the official docs
http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs

```
var stub = sinon.stub(object, "method", func);
```

You could pass a function argument that returns your desired value.

EDIT:

This has been removed from v3.0.0. Instead you should use

```
stub(obj, 'meth').callsFake(fn)
```

Comment: This answer is bit outdated, since `v3.0.0` you should use _callsFake_ to do so, like:
`var stub = sinon.stub(object, "method").callsFake(func);`

Reference [here](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.1.4/stubs/#var-stub--sinonstubobject-method-func).

Comment: The EDIT looks good to me! The specific question is asking about mocks, not stubs, but `callsFake` works on mocks as well.